# Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?

Tags: c

I want to get the length of an array, say `int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4}`. I used `sizeof` to do that.

```
int length(int array[])
{
     return sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printf("%d\n", length(array)); // print 1
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)); // print 4
}
```

So, why the `sizeof(array)` in function `length` returns the pointer size of `array`? But in function `main`, it works.

And, how should I modify the `length` function to get an array's length?

Comment: Yes, I know this is a C++ question, but it contains very useful information concerning C as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A special C rule says that for function parameters, array types are *adjusted* to pointer types. That means:

`int length(int array[]);`

is equivalent to

`int length(int *array);`

So when you compute the `sizeof` the array you are actually computing the size of the pointer.

> (C99, 6.7.5.3p7) "A declaration of a parameter as "array of type" shall    be adjusted to "qualified pointer to type", where the type qualifiers
>           (if any) are those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation."

Comment: ...and the implication of this is that you cannot rewrite `length()` to work as you want - if a function needs to know the size of an array, it needs to be passed to that function as a separate parameter.

Comment: @caf I agree with you. For additional information, it makes sense to do it this way, especially when on an ARM processor with r0, r1, r2, r3 32-bit registers. Therefore a pointer can be passed in r0 rather than having to use stack.

Answer (score 6):

The array decays into a pointer when you pass it into a function.

Answer (score 6):

As the other answerers have noted, a function declared to take an array is compiled the same as if it took a pointer.

The most common way I've seen to do your length method is with a #define, but if you play tricks with templates, you can make your function work.

```
template <size_t _Size> inline int length(int(& array)[_Size])
{
    //return sizeof(array) / sizeof(int);
    return _Size;
};

int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
printf("%d\n", length(array)); // print 4
```

With your array of length 4, this gets compiled as a method that takes an array of length 4, and returns a static 4. This also has the advantage that if you try to pass something that isn't an array, the compiler will give an error, whereas the #define method doesn't.

```
int* foo = array;
printf("%d\n", length(foo)); 
    // error C2784: 'int length(int (&)[_Size])' : could not deduce template
    //     argument for 'int (&)[_Size]' from 'int *'
    // test.cpp(56) : see declaration of 'length'
```

Answer (score 3):

In the main program, the compiler knows the length of the array. In the subroutine, it doesn't. In particular, in a subroutine, a parameter of type `int[]` is identical to a parameter of type `int *`. In the main program, on the other hand, `array` has type `int[4]`. (You can test this by trying to assign another value to `array` in side `main`. The compiler will complain.)

Answer (score 2):

C does not store runtime metadata about the size of an array with the variable.  You will have to store that yourself somewhere.

A variable of type *int[]* in the context of your method *length* is just a pointer to a block of memory.  That's why the size is the same as the size of any other pointer on your system.

When *sizeof* has access to the array at compile-time (as in your *main* function) it will instead return the number of bytes occupied by the array.

Comment: "A variable of type int[] is just a pointer to a block of memory" - that's incorrect in general case. A variable of type `int[]` *is* a block of memory. It is not a pointer. The only contexts where `int[]` stands for a pointer is function parameter declaration and it is a *special case*.

Comment: Clarified that it is a pointer *in the context of the method length()*.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `length` to be aware of the true size of the passed in array, that information has to be passed in, as everyone says. But it is possible for it to receive a reference to the array with the information also built-in:

```
int length(int n, int (* array)[n])
{
     return sizeof(*array) / sizeof(int);
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printf("%d\n", length(4, &array)); // print 1
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)); // print 4
}
```

I don't know what good that actually does you, though, since the size is already provided in the first place. But you see that the `sizeof` operator works as you wanted it to in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable array inside length is not the same as the one outside. You have to keep the sizeof(array) / sizeof(int) in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

To modify your code so that `length` can get the array's length, turn it into a macro:

```
#define length(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x))
```

For your code sample, this will behave as you expect.

Note that this will *only* work on statically-allocated arrays, and only when called using the original array (it won't work when using a pointer to the array).  This is because when you write `sizeof(x)` where `x` is a pointer to an array, the compiler interprets it literally.  It doesn't have any way of mapping `x` back to the array that it points to before evaluating the `sizeof`.