# the sizeof of the array decrease-why

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer)

```
 void print(char arr[]){
  int i;
  printf("%d" , sizeof(arr));  /*print 4**/

}

int main()
{

  char arr[]={0,1,2,3,4};
  printf("%d" , sizeof(arr)); /*print 5**/
  print(arr);
}
```

When I send the array to the function it seems that the size decrease in 1. What happen?

Comment: Asked not too long ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer

Comment: When an array is passed to a function, the function arguments represents the pointer to the first element of the array. So when you try to find the size in the function, you get the size of the pointer as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Because you don't really have an array in the function; it has degraded into a pointer and the size is unknown.  You are asking for the `sizeof` a `char*` which, on your platform, is 4 bytes.