# I got this warning: sizeof on array function parameter will return size of 'const char *' instead of 'const char []'

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer)

I'm new to C, I got an warning from `clang` when compiling my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char *strcpy (char destination[],const char source[]);
int main(void) {
    char str1[] = "this is a very long string";
    char str2[] = "this is a short string";
    strcpy(str2, str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
char *strcpy (char destination[], const char source[]) {
    int size_of_array = sizeof source / sizeof source[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
        destination[i] = source[i];
    }
    return destination;
}
```

I don't know what does the following warning mean:

```
string_copy_withou_pointer.c:12:29: warning: sizeof on array function parameter
      will return size of 'const char *' instead of 'const char []'
      [-Wsizeof-array-argument]
        int size_of_array = sizeof source / sizeof source[0];
                                   ^
string_copy_withou_pointer.c:11:46: note: declared here
char *strcpy (char destination[], const char source[]) {
```

Any idea?

Comment: Other than all the other answers you've got that point out the problems, I'd recommend you to not redefine functions from the standard library. Invent new names, it's safer.

Comment: for the sake of this duplicate question while i don't think its duplicate but concludes the same basic idea, the answer should be as many has mentioned this array will eventually happen to be a pointer which you don't want to get the size of directly instead you need to reference it using sizeof &source on that line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `const char source[]` in argument position is just syntactic sugar for `const char *source`. See, e.g., [Steven Summit's C notes](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/notes/sx10f.html).

In this particular case, you'll want to call `strlen`. When not dealing with strings, pass the size of the array as a separate argument.

Answer (score 11):

This warning is telling you that if you call `sizeof(char[])` you won't get the size of the array but the size of a `char*` pointer.

This means that your variable `size_of_array` will be wrong because it won't represent the size of the real array.

Comment: hwo to fix it then?

Comment: To fix it, you can use the [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) function.

Answer (score 1):

The size of the array doesn't follow when you pass it to the function. Actually it's passed as a pointer which is why the warning message mentions

> will return size of 'const char *'