# Sizeof operator to measure 2D array

Tags: arrays, pointers, memory, sizeof

I'm currently taking a C++ course and we are learning about pointers. The following is an example my professor gave us.

```
int b[3][3];  //Assume integers and memory addresses are 4 bytes
cout << sizeof(b) << endl;  // 36 bytes
cout << sizeof(b+0) << endl;  // 4 bytes
cout << sizeof(*(b+0)) << endl;  //12 bytes
```

I have 2 questions:

1. I tried the second one (`sizeof(b+0)`) and it gives me 8 instead? How come that is the case?
2. Also I want to understand the logic behind the third one (`sizeof(*(b+0)`); is it 12 because it is the total of the first row? Since there are 3 ints and each int is 4 bytes thus it returns 12 bytes in total?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: C is not the same as C++; you should remove the C tag

Comment: sizeof is not a function. it is keyword.

Answer (score 1):

> Sizeof function to ..

[`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is an *operator*, not a function. Read more in [Why is sizeof considered as an operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393582/why-is-sizeof-considered-as-an-operator)

> it gives me 8 instead?

It decays to a *pointer*.

> is it 12 because it is the total of the first row?

Yes. It's like having a 1D array of 3 integers.

---

You might want to check these too:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ g++ -Wall main.cpp 
main.cpp:8:21: warning: sizeof on pointer operation will return size of
      'int (*)[3]' instead of 'int [3][3]' [-Wsizeof-array-decay]
    cout << sizeof(b+0) << endl; // 4 bytes
                   ~^
1 warning generated.
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
36
8
12
4 // sizeof(int)
8 // sizeof(int*)
```

About the warning:

"This warning is telling you that if you call `sizeof(int[])` you won't get the size of the array but the size of an `int*` pointer."

taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13006722/2411320).

Answer (score 0):

1) In systems with 64bits addresses, the pointer have 8 bytes, 64/8.

2) The 2D array is stored as an array of pointers to arrays. So when you do the *(b+0), it is giving to you the contents of the first position of the array b, which is an array of 3 ints. *(b+0) is equivalent to b[0].

Comment: Basically the same answer as the one given by @gsamaras, but written differently. HTH