# Why won't all of my char array get passed (in C)?

Tags: c, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C sizeof a passed array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493281/c-sizeof-a-passed-array)
>   [Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer)

I'm new to C, and am a little confused by the type system. I'm trying to write some code to print the number of lower case characters in a string, but only an int-sized piece of my array gets passed to the cntlower function. Why is this?

```
#include "lecture2.h"

int main(void){
    int lowerAns;
    char toCount[] = "sdipjsdfzmzp";
    printf("toCount size %i\n", sizeof(toCount));
    lowerAns = cntlower(toCount);
    printf("answer %i\n", lowerAns);
}

int cntlower(char str[]) {

    int lowers = 0;
    int i = 0;
    printf("str size %i\n", sizeof(str));
    printf("char size %i\n", sizeof(char));

    for(i = 0; i < (sizeof(str)/sizeof(char)); i++) {
         if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z') {
               lowers++;
         }
    }

    return lowers;

}
```

As it is, the output is currently:
    toCount size 13
    str size 4
    char size 1
    answer 4

I'm sure the reason for this is obvious for some of you, but unfortunately it isn't for me!

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array for similar examples on what you're doing wrong with sizeof and pointers.

Answer (score 2):

A `char str[]` argument to a function is actually syntactic sugar for a `char*`, so `sizeof(str) == sizeof(char*)`. That happens to coincide with `sizeof(int)` on your platform.