# Finding Length of an Array

Tags: c++

I have searched all the way through net but could not find a solution.

I want to find length of an `int` array (number of elements in the array).

Well I am trying to pass array in the function.

I tried

```
void myFunction(int array[])
{
   int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
}
```

but no luck!

Here is the sample code: [Sample Code](http://liveworkspace.org/code/vufqr%2455)

could any one help me in this?

Comment: What is wrong with what you've written?

Comment: That code works. What's your question?

Comment: it returns 1 always. basically sizeof(array) and sizeof(array[0]) both gives value 4

Comment: Then your code is different from what's in the question (e.g. `array` is actually a pointer). Please edit.

Comment: If you're trying to figure out the size by passing `array` to a function it won't work. The array gets implicitly converted to a pointer to the beginning of the array, and the result `1` is that of dividing the size of an `int *` by size of an `int`. This is why posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is important!

Comment: [Look at this](http://liveworkspace.org/code/vufqr$52), it returns 11 as expected. Please update your code so we can see *exactly* what you're doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why sizeof(param\_array) is the size of pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer). Also read this: [How do I use arrays in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c)

Comment: http://liveworkspace.org/code/vufqr$55

Comment: For the record, you want to look at the "Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?" duplicate first. The others were guesses and don't apply directly to your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When arrays are passed into functions, they undergo *array-to-pointer* conversion. This means an array of type `T[N]` will simply *decay* into `T*`. Notice how the size information has been lost. All that remains is a pointer to the first element of the array. Here is a quote from the Standard:

> **4.2 Array-to-pointer conversion**
>
> An lvalue or rvalue of type “array of N T” or “array of unknown bound of T” can be converted to a prvalue
>   of type “pointer to T”. The result is a pointer to the ﬁrst element of the array.

In short, `sizeof( array )` returns the size of the *pointer*, not of the array. That's where the miscalculation derives. A simple solution would be to utilize dynamic containers like `std::vector` which contains its size information internally:

```
#include <vector>

void myFunction(std::vector<int> const &array)
{
    int size = array.size();
}
```

If using `std::vector` isn't an option, you can use a reference to an array instead while using a template argument to deduce the length:

```
template <unsigned N>
void myFunction(int (&array)[N])
{
    int size = N;
}
```

Comment: so is there any way to find the length?

Comment: no actually that is a standard method signature! The array is passed in this way only void myFunction(int array[]). I cannot change the method signature!

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala There's no option but to make some change to the function signature. You can pass the size as an extra parameter, or use a function template to deduce the size of the array, or use some container such as `vector`. Please read the questions I linked to in the comments.

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala: After the array has *decayed* into a pointer, the size information is lost. Either the caller passes the size as a different element, or you change the function signature in some other way (pass a `vector`, or pass the array by reference/pointer)

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala See the edit. You can use templates to get the length.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I appreciate your responses, but this as well doesn't work out for me! I am submitting this code online, and there is a standard method signature, which I cannot change! :) I don't know why people downvoted this question?

Comment: @BurhanuddinSunelwala There is no other way to find the length other than what has been suggested in this thread. You can't keep the method signature in this context.