# Wrong output in Merge Sort Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, mergesort

I've followed all the algorithm steps very carefully , but still this always outputs me the wrong answer. I don't understand why. I think something's wrong in the merge algorithm that's causing this but cannot pinpoint what. Please help. Also if there is anything that can be done to improve the code please suggest.

Thank you

INPUT  - {5,6,1,8,9,7}

OUTPUT - {1,0,7,0,9,7}

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

void mergeSort(int array[],int length);
void merge(int *leftArray,int *rightArray,int *array);

void main()
{

    int array[] = {5,6,1,8,9,7};
    int length_of_array;

    length_of_array = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);

    mergeSort(array,length_of_array);

    int i;

    for(i=0;i<length_of_array;i++)
    {
        printf("%d->",array[i]);
    }
}

void mergeSort(int array[],int length)
{

    if(length <  2)
        return;


    int mid;
    int i;

    mid = length/2;

    int *leftArray, *rightArray;

    leftArray = (int*)malloc(mid*sizeof(int));
    rightArray = (int*)malloc((length-mid)*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<mid;i++)
        leftArray[i] = array[i];

    for(i=mid;i<length;i++)
        rightArray[i-mid] = array[i];


    mergeSort(leftArray, mid);
    mergeSort(rightArray, length-mid);

    merge(leftArray,rightArray,array);

}

void merge(int *leftArray,int *rightArray,int *array)
{
    int i,j,k;
    i = j = k = 0;

    int leftSize = sizeof(leftArray)/sizeof(leftArray[0]);
    int rightSize = sizeof(rightArray)/sizeof(rightArray[0]);

    while(i < leftSize && j < rightSize)
    {
        if(leftArray[i]<rightArray[j])
        {
            array[k] = leftArray[i];
            k = k + 1;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            array[k] = rightArray[j];
            k = k + 1;
            j = j + 1;
        }

    }

    while(i<leftSize)
    {
        array[k] = leftArray[i];
        k = k + 1;
        i = i + 1;

    }

    while(j<rightSize)
    {
        array[k]  = rightArray[j];
        k = k + 1;
        j = j + 1;

    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Use a debugger. 2. This`for(i=mid;i<length;i++)`mightbeperfectly"readable"forthecompilerbutnotsoforhumans.

Comment: There are zeros in your output, but not in the input. That makes me suspect that you have copied zeros from somewhere esle into your array, probably from beyond the end of the array.

Comment: Thank you will use proper spacing next time :)

Comment: `sizeof(leftArray)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`. You need to pass the number of elements as parameters.

Comment: Not related to the problem but anyways: [do **not** cast the result of `malloc() in C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Sidenote: Enable all recommended warnings, including `-Wconversion` (gcc, check your compiler for the equivalent). `sizeof` yields a `size_t`, not an `int` and you should not mix unsigned with signed.

Comment: How can I enable it in Ubuntu terminal ? @Olaf

Comment: @VineethSai: Get a C book and read the documentation of the tools. The gcc and clang documentation are very clear!

Comment: Also `void main()` is an illegal signature (I wonder why your compiler does not warn, might be another missing warning option).

Comment: Okay sorry for that

Comment: unrelated : Use `<stdlib.h>` instead of `<malloc.h>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by @molbdnilo, you can't get the size of an array from a pointer parameter. So `merge` needs to take the length of the left and right arrays as well as the pointers to them.

The issue is that arrays in C are not a 'complete' data type, but rather just a convenient syntax. In your `merge` function, the parameter `int *leftArray` is exactly what it says - a pointer to an integer. So `sizeof` will tell you the size of a pointer. In your `main` function, `array` is known to be an array, and its length is known (from the initial value given), so `sizeof` can give the actual size of memory allocated to that variable. But that size is not stored anywhere with the variable, so it is not passed into `merge` - the only thing passed in is the pointer to the block of memory.

In addition, while it won't be causing you problems in this case, you should be `free`ing the `leftArray` and `rightArray` pointers that you `malloc`. That way you can use your sorting function in an actual application without leaking memory.

Comment: Thank you very much sir , it worked when I passed the value back into the function. Is it possible to tell why exactly it's not possible ? Isn't is the same as sizeof array ?

Comment: @VineethSai: Because of arrays decaying to pointers, see here: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying) and [Why sizeof(param_array) is the size of pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer).

Comment: And  [Length of array in function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8269048/length-of-array-in-function-argument)

Comment: @VineethSai You're welcome. See my edit to the answer