# Segmentation fault ("Invalid read of size 4" when in a code visualizer)

Tags: c

I have to make a blackjack in c using the Graphic Library of our school and i'm on the motor of the game. I tried to use struct for a card with value and the symbol, an array of 52 cards using calloc and i've made 2 functions :

The function should return 1 if there's 2 identical cards  :

```
int TestPaire(Carte *Jeu[]){ // La Fonction renvoie 1 s'il y a une paire, 0 sinon
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*Jeu); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(*Jeu); i++)
        {
            if (Jeu[i]->Chiffre == Jeu[j]->Chiffre && i != j)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function who return the total of the cards's values :

```
int CompteCarte(Carte *Jeu[]){ // La Fonction renvoie la valeur totale des cartes
    int compteur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(*Jeu); i++)
    {
        compteur += Jeu[i]->Chiffre;
    }
    
    return compteur;
}
```

and there's my main :

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Carte* Jeu = (Carte*)calloc(52, sizeof(Carte));
    Jeu[0].Chiffre = 3;
    Jeu[1].Chiffre = 1;
    Jeu[2].Chiffre = 6;
    int a = CompteCarte(&Jeu);
    printf("%d\n", a);
    int b = TestPaire(&Jeu);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

```
typedef struct Carte {
    int Chiffre;
    char Couleur[10];
} Carte;
```

And when runnig it in a code visualizer, it add the first value to the variable "compteur", but not the 2nd and return : "Invalid read of size 4". And in WSL, I have a segmentation fault. It just returns 10 then a 0 in the console.

Any help and/or advice (specially on pointers and dynamic allocation) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This code `i < sizeof(*Jeu)` clearly does not what you might expect it to do. `sizeof *Jeu` is the size of the struct in bytes. It does not relate to the number of elements you allocated memory for. You cannot use it as index for `Jeu[j]`. You must pass the number of elements as another parameter to your function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why sizeof(param\_array) is the size of pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622146/why-sizeofparam-array-is-the-size-of-pointer)

Comment: That duplicate is a tiny bit different as you use `*Jeu` instead of the pointer itself but the problem is the same.

Comment: I just saw there is another error in your code. Your compiler should warn you that you pass an argument of incompatible type. Your function expects an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array. The correct parameter list would be `Carte Jeu[]` or `Carte *Jeu` which are identical. That doesn't solve the issue with calculating the size.

Comment: @Gerhardh so to get the size of an array using an array i should use " sizeof(jeu)/sizeof(*Jeu) ?

Comment: No, as I wrote in my first comment, `sizeof` does not retrieve the size of the allocated memory. It will result in the size of a pointer. Read my comments carefully and also read the linked question again. Together with the answers, of course.

Comment: @DilDeath In C, there is no way to retrieve the size of an array that was passed into a function. You have to manually record the length of the array when you create it, and explicitly provide that information to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing a double pointer to a function can result in some cryptic errors and segmentation faults (like in your case) and is usually never mandatory (unless you're doing some truly cursed stuff). You already have `Jeu` as a `Carte*` - why not just pass that directly to `CompteCarte` and `TestPaire`? If you need the size of the array, you would have to pass that as a second parameter:

For example, for `CompteCarte`:

```
int CompteCarte(Carte* Jeu, int size) { // La Fonction renvoie la valeur totale des cartes
    int compteur = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        compteur += Jeu[i].Chiffre;
    }
    
    return compteur;
}
```

and in `main`:

```
int a = CompteCarte(Jeu, 52 /* or whatever the size of Jeu is */);
```